# Access individual cells in csv file with python

Tags: python, regex, parsing, csv

How can I access individual cells in a csv document to parse and edit them? Also is there a way I can convert the csv document into a two-dimensional array?

Comment: what have you tried ... and why is there a bioinformatics tag on this post?

Comment: Python has a [CSV module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Comment: python csv module, csv.DictReader, you can also have a look a pandas, numpy

Comment: I forgot to share that I have imported the csv file using the csv module. Is there a way to do either things using that specific module?

Comment: @JoranBeasley sorry I put that bioinformatics tag in there. It was by accident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to want to use the [csv package](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) that is made for python.  You may want to try something like this (assuming your file is regularly structured and has no headers):

```
data = []
for row in csv.reader(open('you_file.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=',')
    data.append(row)
```

Give that a try and look through the [csv package](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) docs to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for you.

```
import csv

twoDimArray = [] 

with open('input.csv', 'rb') as csvfile: 
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='|') 
    for row in reader: 
        twoDomArray.append(row) 

#DO STUFF WITH DATA 

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as csvfile: 
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ', 
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL) 
    for row in twoDinArray: 
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Also read the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Best of luck :)